# Use SageMaker Pytorch image for training

Tags: amazon-web-services, pytorch, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to containerize the training process for a fine tuned BERT model and run it on SageMaker. I was planning to use the pre-built SageMaker Pytorch GPU containers (https://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/available-deep-learning-containers-images/) as my starting point but I am having issues pulling the images during my build process.

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
# SageMaker PyTorch image
FROM 763104351884.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/pytorch-training:1.5.0-gpu-py36-cu101-ubuntu16.04


ENV PATH="/opt/ml/code:${PATH}"

# /opt/ml and all subdirectories are utilized by SageMaker, we use the /code subdirectory to store our user code.
COPY /bert /opt/ml/code

# this environment variable is used by the SageMaker PyTorch container to determine our user code directory.
ENV SAGEMAKER_SUBMIT_DIRECTORY /opt/ml/code

# this environment variable is used by the SageMaker PyTorch container to determine our program entry point
# for training and serving.
# For more information: https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-pytorch-container
ENV SAGEMAKER_PROGRAM bert/train
```

My build_and_push script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# This script shows how to build the Docker image and push it to ECR to be ready for use
# by SageMaker.

# The argument to this script is the image name. This will be used as the image on the local
# machine and combined with the account and region to form the repository name for ECR.
IMAGE="my-bert"

# parameters
PY_VERSION="py36"

# Get the account number associated with the current IAM credentials
account=$(aws sts get-caller-identity --query Account --output text)

if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    exit 255
fi

chmod +x bert/train

# Get the region defined in the current configuration (default to us-west-2 if none defined)
region=$(aws configure get region)
region=${region:-us-east-2}

# If the repository doesn't exist in ECR, create it.
aws ecr describe-repositories --repository-names ${IMAGE} || aws ecr create-repository --repository-name ${IMAGE}

echo "---> repository done.."
# Get the login command from ECR and execute it directly
aws ecr get-login-password --region $region | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $account.dkr.ecr.$region.amazonaws.com
echo "---> logged in to account ecr.."

# Get the login command from ECR in order to pull down the SageMaker PyTorch image
# aws ecr get-login-password --region $region | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 763104351884.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
# echo "---> logged in to pytorch ecr.."

echo "Building image with arch=gpu, region=${region}"
TAG="gpu-${PY_VERSION}"
FULLNAME="${account}.dkr.ecr.${region}.amazonaws.com/${IMAGE}:${TAG}"
docker build -t ${IMAGE}:${TAG} --build-arg ARCH="$arch" -f "Dockerfile" .
docker tag ${IMAGE}:${TAG} ${FULLNAME}
docker push ${FULLNAME}
```

I get the following message during the push and the sagemaker pytorch image is not pulled:

```
Get https://763104351884.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/pytorch-training/manifests/1.5.0-gpu-py36-cu101-ubuntu16.04: no basic auth credentials
```

Please let me know if this is the correct way to use a pre-built SageMaker image and what I could do to fix this error.

Answer (score 5):

You should run something like this, before running the docker build:

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region ${region} | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 763104351884.dkr.ecr.${region}.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 1):

This image (763104351884.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/pytorch-training:1.5.0-gpu-py36-cu101-ubuntu16.04) is hosted in ECR.

So when you want to pull it, make sure you have the correct AWS configuration (with your own AWS account's security tokens) and have run ecr login command before pulling the image.

Example:

aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1 --registry-ids 763104351884

Comment: this helped solving the issue for me